# Tuba sheet music: which octave to play?

Tags: tuba

I learned Tuba on a BBb in North America.  Beginner ranges were typically around C2-C3 (below the bass-clef staff to mid-staff) with intermediate stuff rarely reaching C4 (1 ledger line above the staff).  C2 or lower is my normal go-to area.  It's extremely rare, even in orchestral stuff to see more than 2 ledger lines above the staff.

However, I'm planning to join a band in The Netherlands.  I received parts for:

- Bb Bass (C3-C4+)
- Besbas BC (C3-C4+)
- Tuba in Bb TC (C3-C4+)  (says TC, but it is in bass clef)
- Tuba in Bb BC (C3-C5)
- Bb Basses (C3-C5ish-- 3 ledger lines above the staff)

In none of these parts, does the music go below the staff (a very comfortable place for me to play).

The lack of C2-C3 range has me wondering if they gave me Euphonium/Baritone parts, or whether I should drop it one octave.  Sitting up at C4 for so long is going to be quite the work-out otherwise!

Comment: I would suggest asking the band you plan to join for clarification. They will most likely know best what they want.

Comment: First: what is the actual lowest note (fundamental) your tuba produces?  Second: what is shown on a tuba fingering chart?  That should solve this issue, at least for modern published music.  There could well be different conventions 150 years ago.

Comment: 1st thing I'd do is listen to some  recordings of the pieces you have charts for. You'll be able to hear what the tuba parts play in them, and make up your mind. 2nd thing is ask the bandleader, who may well give you the freedom to play where you want.

Comment: The parts are almost certainly notated an octave or a major ninth too high (treating the tuba as a B-flat transposing instrument). Anything in treble clef sounds two octave and a major second lower.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transposing bass clef instruments for Tuba, Bombardon, and Contrabass](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/102039/transposing-bass-clef-instruments-for-tuba-bombardon-and-contrabass)

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  Indeed the music was a ninth too high.  The linked issue helped me understand the phrase "Bes".  I hadn't even considered that it was off by more than an octave!  Good tips.  I asked for the list of parts, and they had given me "Bb Bass" parts instead of my expected "Bass" parts.